# Weird 'string' declared here error. Trying to program pyramid of asterisks

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++, so I'm still trying to figure out how to do basic debugging from errors printed on the terminal. I'm trying to print a pyramid of asterisks (*), but I keep getting this error that says "'string' declared here". /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/iosfwd:194:65: note: 
      'string' declared here
typedef basic_string, allocator > string;
                                                                ^
1 error generated.

I've tried looking up how to read some of these errors in C++, but haven't been able to find a useful guide that isn't written in some alien technical gibberish. So if you could dumb down the explanation a little that would be great.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

String printAst(int number){
    for(int i = 0; i < number; i++){
        cout << "* ";
    }
}
int main(){

printAst(3);
//***
//**
//*
return 0;

}
```

I have the expected print out listed in //

Comment: One obvious potential problem is that the `printAst()` function returns a string, but you have no return statement.

Comment: That isn't an error message it's a note about the error message on the line above in the compiler output

Comment: The error message probably says something like "String is undefined, did you mean string?"

Comment: You need to print '\n' to go to the next line.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I was confused about the return type, since I couldn't figure out whether cout counted as a string return, or whether I should have made the return type void

Comment: I have given you a suggested version below.

Comment: @stark Ya, I started out just testing to see if I could print the first line, but ran into problems with those errors I mentioned. I should have changed the expected output to show just the first line

Answer (score 0):

Here is a corrected version of your code.  The immediate cause of your current errors appears to have been the `String` return type of the `printAst()` function.  If you wanted to return a string, then you probably intended to use `std::string`, not `String`.  But, even after fixing this, I noticed that your logic for printing the pyramid also had a problem, so I fixed that too.

```
void printAst (int number) {
    for (int i=0; i < number; ++i) {
        for (int j=0; j < number-i; ++j) {
            cout << "* ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
}

int main() {
    printAst(3);
    return 0;
}

* * * 
* * 
*
```

The major changes I made include using a double `for` loop to print the inverse pyramid.  The logic is that there are `number` levels to the pyramid, and at each level we print `number` count of asterisks.

Also, since `printAst` does not return anything, I changed the return type to `void`.

Comment: Ya, I ended up reaching the same conclusion regarding the typing being void and using the nested for loop. What I'm still confused about is how I know the type should be void. I thought initially since I'm printing a string "*" the return type should be string, but now I'm not sure.

Comment: The `printAst` function does not actually return any value, thus it should be void.  That is prints out a string has nothing to do with its return behavior.